# Composite Fermat's numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that Fermat's numbers are $F_n= 2^{2^n} +1$. 
My question is: does there exist certain forms of $n$ for which $F_n$ is always composite?

Comment: As far as I know, it's open whether there are infinitely many composite Fermat numbers.

Comment: I bet all $n>4$ )))

Comment: sir, I asked for certain forms of n. I mean certain types of n or some specific types of n.

Comment: @ michael : can you prove it sir?

Comment: @SubhashChandBhoria, it's well-known open problem.

Comment: @ michael : ok sir

Answer (score 2):

We don't know. According to [prothsearch](http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html), $F_{3329780}$ is the largest Fermat number that is known to be composite.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(1)=1$, and let $f(n+1)=2^{2^{f(n)}}$ for every positive integer $n$.

Let $\Phi$ denote the statement:
if a system $S \subseteq \{x_i \cdot x_j=x_k: i,j,k \in \{1,...,17\}\}
\cup \{2^{2^{x_i}}=x_k: i,k \in \{1,...,17\}\} $ has only finitely many solutions in non-negative 
integers $x_1,...,x_{17}$, then each such solution $(x_1,...,x_{17})$ satisfies $x_1,...,x_{17} \leq f(17)$.

Theorem. If the statement $\Phi$ is true, and if $2^{2^n}+1$ is composite for some integer $n \geq f(15)$,
then $2^{2^n}+1$ is composite for infinitely many non-negative integers $n$.

Reference:

A. Tyszka, [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3826)
A conjecture which implies that there exists a computable upper bound for the
heights of solutions of a Diophantine equation with a finite number of solutions,

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3826