# Can we deduce that there is infinitely many indices $n$ such that the period length of $1/(2^{2^n}+1)$ is strictly less then $2^{2^n}$.

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps, fermat-numbers

In this page (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html) we have the following result:

$2^{2^n}+1$ is a Fermat prime if and only if the period length of $1/(2^{2^n}+1)$ is equal to $2^{2^n}$. In other words, Fermat primes are full reptend primes.

Thus, we get:

$2^{2^n}+1$ is **not** a Fermat prime if and only if the period length of $1/(2^{2^n}+1)$ is strictly less then $2^{2^n}$. See: [Period of the decimal expression for the rational number $\frac{1}{n}$ is at most $n-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140170/period-of-the-decimal-expression-for-the-rational-number-frac1n-is-at-mos?rq=1)

My **question** is: Can we deduce that there is infinitely many indices $n$ such that the period length of $1/(2^{2^n}+1)$ is strictly less then $2^{2^n}$.

Comment: @Sil: From this can we say that this problem is undecidable!

Comment: I think it is just undecided, undecidable would mean that someone actually proved that it cannot be answered, but the fact is that we just don't know.

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer and cleaned the comments.

Comment: Probably, there is no Fermat prime beyond $\ n=4\ $ , but in fact , as mentioned in the answer, we do not even know whether infinite many Fermat numbers are composite. The first unknown case is $\ n=33\ $

Comment: @Helena Considering Goedel's results , we do not even know whether a statement like "There are infinite many composite Fermat numbers" can be proven or disproven. It might be independent of ZFC like the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @Peter: Yes. I just read about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing existence of infinitely many such $n$'s would imply infinitely many $n$'s for which Fermat numbers are composite, which is an open problem (and as suggested in comments, period of $1/n$ cannot be larger than $n-1$). See also [Composite Fermat's numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366312/composite-fermats-numbers) and [Period of the decimal expression for the rational number $\frac{1}{n}$ is at most $n-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140170/period-of-the-decimal-expression-for-the-rational-number-frac1n-is-at-mos?rq=1).

Comment: Good answer! But how can the period be strictly larger than $2^{2^n}$ ?

Comment: @Peter Good catch, updated.